# Where to post game cheats?

Tags: nintendo-wii, new-super-mario-bros-wii, cheats

My ten year old son spent several hours mapping out the Power Up Panels in New Super Mario Bro's Wii, and now he'd like to share his findings with the internet masses.  The trouble is, I don't know much about where to share the fruits of his labor.  I created a web page to host his maps:

http://JumpingFishes.com/PowerUpPanels .

Can you recommend a forum or other venue that would appreciate all of my son's hard work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually look to [gamefaqs.com](http://gamefaqs.com). Though they are primarily limited to text-based data they do have a form to submit maps and images (and I think this qualifies).

Looking at the [New Super Mario Bros. Wii](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs) section, I notice that there are already several FAQs that feature the same data collected by your son (though his versions are nicer looking). I would look into uploading it there anyway if he is so obliged, as GameFAQs is no stranger to redundancy.